# Connect elements on android view

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app and my app must show a matrix of elements where some are connected by a line (like paths). I'm programmer but I don't have a clear idea on how to do this (the graphical part) [image: Image, the information will be retrieved from a database. So it should support vertical and horizontal scroll]because still I'm starting in android development, but if you have an idea please to resolve this graphical problem, give me some help then I would research more about it.

Note: I want to create an app for my college, where an student could mark their passed courses, and there are courses that must be marked (passed) to mark others and know their progress on the career.

Like this image..

[image: courses on the career.]

Comment: I think your best solution would be to draw this in GIMP and then you can put an event listener on that image

Comment: Thanks! But if I want that each element must it be a view that shows a tiny textview and a button to show more information?

Comment: If you have to show your layout like that, I think you will have to look into SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

Use  **Grid View** because GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter. to Achieve your goal you must use custom grid view to make that but am not sure about the lines.

check out this tutorials it would help to make that .

- [Example 1:](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677)
- [Example 2](http://android-peoplesconnect.blogspot.com/2014/01/custom-gridview-example-in-android.html)
- [Example 3:](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html)

Comment: Great! The problem now is with the lines to connect the elements